# Python 030 == 24 is True, How is that correct?

Tags: python

I came across the following problem:

As you would expect:

```
>>> [01,02,03]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Adding superflous `0`'s to the front of an integer `N` results in the mathematical equivalent of the integer `0N`, i.e `N`.

However when I do:

```
>>> [030, 031, 031, 031, 030, 031, 031, 032, 031, 032]
[24, 25, 25, 25, 24, 25, 25, 26, 25, 26]
```

This notion is proved to be *completly* incorrect. I tried to figure out why this was the case by trying to check if `030` is an int:

```
>>> type(030)
<type 'int'>
```

Then I thought so perhaps, `030` is being evaluted to `24` and then it's instead getting `type(24)`. So I thought looking to see what's happening with `dis` might help:

```
>>> dis.dis('n=030')
          0 JUMP_FORWARD    12349 (to 12352)
          3 DELETE_SLICE+1 
          4 <48>           
>>> dis.dis('n=30')
          0 JUMP_FORWARD    13117 (to 13120)
          3 <48>
```

This didn't help clear up why this behaviour occurs. So, what is the reson behind this behaviour?

And as per the title:

```
>>> 030 == 24
True
```

Comment: `030` means 30 octal, so 24.

Comment: The newest version of Python doesn't let you shoot yourself in the leg like this. Leading zero no longer means an octal literal. In fact, leading zeros in numbers are completely disallowed.

Comment: @BrenBarn You're right this question essentially is the same, my wording I suppose made that result not come up in the similarity check.

Answer (score 10):

The leading `0` means octal or base8. This is defined behaviour for Python2, but due to the confusion it has caused you now need to write `0o30` in Python3 as you would write `0x18` for a hexidecimal number

the `0o30` syntax also works in Python2.7, so it's a good idea to use this if you do wish to write octal literals

This is also why `08` and `09` will cause errors - 8 and 9 aren't valid octal digits

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense, still quite confusing though *definitely* not what I would expect.

Comment: @HennyH Hence the change of behaviour in 3.x. As well designed as Python is, there are cases of mistakes being made. Fortunately they are also being fixed.

Comment: @HennyH, It's not unique to Python - lots of languages interpret the leading 0 that way

Answer (score 1):

`030` is an octal notation, and is 3*8 so 24.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `0` to the front of a python number makes it into an *octal number*. Hence `030` = 3 * 8 = 24 in decimal notation.